# How to stop a toggle event from triggering on navigation

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

So my Xamarin.Forms app uses Prism, and it works mostly fine.
I have created a settings page with uses Switches to make certain choices and as such I have a Toggle event handler in the code behind which also works, does what it is supposed to.
The problem I am having now is to try and stop the toggle method from triggering when navigating from the page, which it automatically does on navigation.
I found a solution for this for a previous prism version, 7.0.0.396, by stopping the method in the ondisappearing method and doing

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
        switch.Toggled -= switch_OnToggled;
    }
```

this works fine because the ondiappearing method triggers and stops the toggle events before they are triggered by the navigation, but it doesn't work for the newer prism versions because in the newer version the toggle methods are triggering before the ondisappearing method can stop them.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve the problem by using the Xamarin.Forms.BehaviorsPack, and using the EventToCommandBehavior to bind the events to a command in my ViewModel.